# Teams notifications from Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, microsoft-teams

I have configured teams notifications from Azure Data Factory using the below Microsoft documentation and want to make some changes with font colours. See below for my requirement -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-send-notifications-to-teams?tabs=data-factory

Right now I have my notifications displayed as below and I would like to change the font colour of 'Pipeline Status'. Is there a way I can do it?

[image: Teams Notification]

Answer (score 0):

As of now text color is not supported for messages card but you can use [Text Formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/message-card-reference#text-formatting) for messages card.